# Low disk space and partition problem on dual booted system

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage

I use Ubuntu 14.04 alongwith Windows 8 and keep getting low disk space warning:

[System Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZPmx.png)

[df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt5bw.png)

As you see the sda8 partition has 95% used up space. I do not understand how to clean it up?
I am a new user, and the partitioning and installing was done by a friend. I'd be grateful if someone can explain if this is an efficient way on partitioning or not.
I have already used the clean, autoclean and autoremove commands, so please do not suggest that.

Edit:
[ls /boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTnhI.png)

Comment: Can you list the contents of "/boot" to be sure that you dont have a bunch of older kernels?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I have added a screenshot of the contents of /boot, if that'd help.

Comment: Thanks - it's generally better to copy the text from your terminal and paste it into the question.  So you do not have an excess of kernels (good!) but possibly a directory has become full of files.  The following command will list the files in your directory large-to-small, so you can see if a directory has too much stuff in it.  first, change to root directory:  `cd /`  and then run the command `sudo du -cksh * | sort -hr | head -n 15`  This does take a while, so be patient.

Comment: Having looked for large directories, (ignore "/mnt/C6E.." and "/mount/hp/7C..." and "/mnt/hp/3E/...") your "/home" directory is often the largest directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `du` command you can quickly narrow down where your space is being taken up.  With the following command you can ignore other filesystems like mount points that may not be relevant in your search and also return only the top directory of the largest folders.  They are then sorted with the largest at the bottom in my opinion making it easier to see the largest ones.

```
sudo du -hxd 1 / | sort -h
```

Examples:

```
$ sudo du -hxd 1 / | sort -h
```

Returns (and I am truncating these lists because they are long):

```
32M /etc
132M    /boot
455M    /root
757M    /lib
1.4G    /opt
8.1G    /var
21G /usr
67G /home
98G /
```

In the above, we can see that `/home` is the largest because the `/` is the total of the drive.

Now, looking in my home folder we should be able to narrow down more:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo du -hxd 1 /home | sort -h
937M    /home/share
67G /home
67G /home/terrance
```

Now we see that my home folder itself is the largest.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo du -hxd 1 /home/terrance | sort -h
802M    /home/terrance/.config
1.1G    /home/terrance/cuda_samples
1.5G    /home/terrance/MacCrap
2.5G    /home/terrance/.cache
4.1G    /home/terrance/ROMS
7.8G    /home/terrance/.PlayOnLinux
11G /home/terrance/.steam
14G /home/terrance/.local
22G /home/terrance/Downloads
67G /home/terrance
```

Now we can see that my `Downloads` and `.local` folders are the largest.  I am not worried about my `Downloads` right now, but the `.local` seems kind of large.  Lets look further:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo du -hxd 1 /home/terrance/.local | sort -h
8.0K    /home/terrance/.local/.AppleDouble
40K /home/terrance/.local/bin
344M    /home/terrance/.local/lib
13G /home/terrance/.local/share
14G /home/terrance/.local
```

The `share` folder is taking up the most here.  Lets look further:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo du -hxd 1 /home/terrance/.local/share | sort -h
11M /home/terrance/.local/share/tracker
13M /home/terrance/.local/share/fish
57M /home/terrance/.local/share/supertuxkart
145M    /home/terrance/.local/share/akonadi
517M    /home/terrance/.local/share/baloo
13G /home/terrance/.local/share
13G /home/terrance/.local/share/gnome-boxes
```

Well, `gnome-boxes` is pretty large.  That is a VM program (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Boxes) that I removed a while back but it looks as though the image that I created is still hanging around.  I am going to delete it: **WARNING: Never remove a folder or file that you are unsure of as you might crash your system.**

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ rm -rf /home/terrance/.local/share/gnome-boxes
```

Now when I run the original command again I get that only 86G is used now:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo du -hxd 1 / | sort -h
455M    /root
757M    /lib
1.4G    /opt
8.1G    /var
21G /usr
55G /home
86G /
```

Hopefully this might help you determine where all your space is being used and what you can remove from your system safely to regain unused space.